# Error in generating C# classes using xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd.exe

I have XML file from which I want to make C# classes by using xsd.exe tool. But upon running the tool, it gives following error

> Cannot add a nested relation or an element column to a table containing a simplecontent column

I am using this statement

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>xsd d:\XMLResponse.xml /o:d:\
```

Above discussed xml is a response so I want to make class of it in order to manipulate that response.

XML file is so much long that I can't paste it so I am giving a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vap2ba191p5q1bb/GCF_Response.xml) for it. Link sharing is just for the sake of understanding the problem and nothing else.

Comment: @Adriano I have already saw that question but I could not see any repetitive xml element with different structure in my xml.

Comment: xsd has a long sight, it can! :) Try to generate schema instead of code, it's easier to inspect than raw XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @Adriano I have already saw that question but I could not see any repetitive xml element with different structure in my xml.

There are two things mentioned in the other thread:

1) Your problem is you have the same element name with a different structure somewhere in the document.

2) It looks like your xml contains an element which has both text children (simple content) and other element children.

After a very quick inspection I found an example of *both* in your xml:

Line 172:

```
<ConditionValues> ConditionValuesDefinitionType </ConditionValues>
```

Line 306 and further:

```
<ConditionValues> ConditionValuesType 
  <Condition> ConditionType 
    <DisplayName> string </DisplayName> 
    <ID> int </ID> 
  </Condition> 
  <!-- ... more Condition nodes allowed here ... -->
  <ConditionHelpURL> anyURI </ConditionHelpURL> 
</ConditionValues>
```

Comment: +1 for the patience to check his XML instead of him

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class GetCategoryFeaturesResponse
{
string m_Category = "";
public string Category {
    get { return m_Category; }
    set { m_Category = value; }
}

string m_CategoryVersion = "";
public string CategoryVersion {
    get { return m_CategoryVersion; }
    set { m_CategoryVersion = value; }
}

string m_FeatureDefinitions = "";
public string FeatureDefinitions {
    get { return m_FeatureDefinitions; }
    set { m_FeatureDefinitions = value; }
}

string m_SiteDefaults = "";
public string SiteDefaults {
    get { return m_SiteDefaults; }
    set { m_SiteDefaults = value; }
}

string m_UpdateTime = "";
public string UpdateTime {
    get { return m_UpdateTime; }
    set { m_UpdateTime = value; }
}

string m_Ack = "";
public string Ack {
    get { return m_Ack; }
    set { m_Ack = value; }
}

string m_Build = "";
public string Build {
    get { return m_Build; }
    set { m_Build = value; }
}

string m_CorrelationID = "";
public string CorrelationID {
    get { return m_CorrelationID; }
    set { m_CorrelationID = value; }
}

string m_Errors = "";
public string Errors {
    get { return m_Errors; }
    set { m_Errors = value; }
}

string m_HardExpirationWarning = "";
public string HardExpirationWarning {
    get { return m_HardExpirationWarning; }
    set { m_HardExpirationWarning = value; }
}

string m_Timestamp = "";
public string Timestamp {
    get { return m_Timestamp; }
    set { m_Timestamp = value; }
}

string m_Version = "";
public string Version {
    get { return m_Version; }
    set { m_Version = value; }
}
  }
```

I havent checked the code ,generated through this [tool](http://code-w.com/Tools/Xml-to-Class-Generator)
**P.S:** I removed the xml comments it was making the tool crazy :)